# Raspberry Pi Zero W stuck in rainbow boot loop when connected to battery powered power supply

Tags: power-supply, pi-zero

I found that my battery powered power supply was outputting 4.89V after checking it with a multimeter. Is this not enough to power a pi zero? When I plug the pi into the wall everything is fine. However, when I plug it into the battery powered power supply, it just keeps going to the rainbow screen, the startup screen, and then back to the rainbow screen. Is there anything I should check on the power supply besides the voltage to see why it won't effectively power the pi?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official answer is **all models require a 5.1V supply** as documented on the RPF site [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/power/README.md).

As power needs increase (CPU needs / screen / USB / GPIO) many chargers / supplies will drop the voltage to cope with the increased current demands.  This often leads to a reboot loop as CPU requirements during boot are high.

Make sure the max current draw can cope with a fully loaded system (see above linked page) without draining the battery or cooking it and that you have a decent cable between the supply and the Pi.

Comment: Yup, it was the wire! Just needed a higher gauge. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

The voltage should ideally be 5.1 Volts and the recommended current capacity is 1.2 Amps for a Pi Zero.

You should use at least 18AWG cable and no unnecessary connections that can cause voltage drop between the power and the Pi.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/power/README.md

Comment: Just got a new short, higher gauge micro usb cable and it works like a charm. Thank you!